# JQuery misreading serverside csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, raspberry-pi

I have written a program on the Raspberry Pi to read GPIO inputs and write them to a .csv file which is then read by a Javascript script and displayed on a webpage hosted on the Pi.

The Pi polls the pins and writes to the file every 0.1 seconds and the script reads this file every 0.2 seconds and updates the webpage.

The problem I am having is that sometimes the script will read the values as all zeroes rather than the actual numbers saved in the file without throwing any errors. This occurs randomly and sometimes the script does read the file correctly. refreshing the page, restarting apache and rebooting the Pi seem to have no effect.

The fact that the script returns no errors leads me to believe the problem occurs before the script gets the file but viewing the file in `cat` shows the correct values.

Anyone have any ideas?

The relevant Javascript code:

```
var csv_path = "/data/loads.csv";

function update_vars() {

//get latest data
var response = $.get(csv_path, function(data) {
    var csv_string = data;
    var res = csv_string.split("\n")[1].split(",");

    //parse values into variables
    ...
});
```

Sample file contents:

```
TV,AC,Oven,Light,Solar,inverter,inverter(controlled)
1,3,2,6,0,0,0
```

Sample Javascript log output:

```
TV,AC,Oven,Light,Solar,inverter,inverter(controlled)
0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: I would check the code on the server that parses/sends the data.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. The csv file is saved in the data/ directory of the server and is read directly from there with the $.get command in JQuery. The values are already wrong before the javascript gets to the parsing to variables stage

Comment: Maybe it's a conflict? i.e. the JS is attempting to read the CSV while it is being modified by the PI system

Comment: So it seems I need to redesign the way I pass data to the JS. Would I be better off trying to implement some kind of lockfile or diving into learning mySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem by replacing the csv file and javascript with a MySQL database and php.

Now my python adds an entry to the database with a php script selecting the right values and displaying them. This has the advantage of not needing to process anything client side as well.

It feels like a bit of overkill for my application but it seems to be working much better, not to mention the nice side effect of understanding what a LAMP stack is now.